# Virus Total report lists 48 different types of malware in a file, are they all the same?

Tags: windows, malware, windows-11, malware-detection

I bought a code scanner for my car on Amazon and it came with a USB key with the drivers, etc.  Windows Defender identified malware on it and appears to have cleaned it up from my Windows 11 PC.  I was wondering if there could be other stuff that Defender didn't catch so I uploaded it to virustotal.com using a Linux machine.  Forty eight of the vendors identified it as malware, but they all call it something different.  I'm not sure if they're 48 different names for the same malware or what.  Here's a link to the [report](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/89b72cdcb06fd1aeb15c21e9f00047d3c21620b25113a8d1f99a8a0627d78738/detection)

Comment: Modern malware scanners don't just detect a certain string as a certain piece of malware. I mean, they do that too, but shit got more complicated. See [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphic_code) and [heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_analysis).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)

Comment: each company is responsible for their own taxonomy, so while we can't really tell if they are all the same, it is not unexpected that each detection by a different company will have a different name.

Comment: It seems that looking through the various details tabs that the file is some kind of generic compromise tool based on AutoIt to drop a payload and run it. In the details under **File Version Information** it mentions **http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/**. It is probable that all the various vendors see some malicious behaviour in whatever payload the script runs based on machine learning and they all have their own way of defining and recognising it based on various strings and snippets and actions. We cannot guess if they all saw the exact same file or saw something similar.

Comment: Honestly it’s also possible it’s harmless and the entire problem is due to the use of AutoIt. Would I trust it? I Absolutely would toss the USB key immediately

Comment: AutoIt is pretty easy to decompile, but I wouldn't bother. Before you toss it in the trash, destroy it physically so that no one else gets infected. Most (but not all) AVs can tell the difference between a malicious and non-malicious AutoIt script based on behaviour (e.g. which dlls they call), and this one is probably malicious.